# Square Brackets sql query error

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sqlserver

I am receiving an error:

> The query syntax is invalid
>
> Error while processing square brackets

I have tried to run it with and without brackets and still receive the same error. Please also note that the same query runs fine referencing FROM _Sent

```
SELECT s.SubscriberKey, ss.EmailAddress, MIN(s.EventDate) as 'FirstClickDate', o.ACCT_NUM, o.ACCT_NM, o.BUYER_CONTACT_UID, o.CONTACT_GUID, o.FIRST_NM, o.LAST_NM, o.EMAIL_ADDR, o.PHONE
FROM _Click s 
JOIN _job j ON j.JobID = s.JobID AND j.accountid = 1059291
JOIN ENT._subscribers ss ON s.SubscriberID = ss.SubscriberID
JOIN [MHAT_ImportDE] o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.CONTACT_GUID
WHERE (j.EmailName = ‘MHAT_Email1' and s.EventDate >= '8/5/2016')
Group by 
s.SubscriberKey, ss.EmailAddress, o.ACCT_NUM, 
o.ACCT_NM, o.BUYER_CONTACT_UID, o.CONTACT_GUID, o.FIRST_NM,
o.LAST_NM, o.EMAIL_ADDR, o.PHONE
```

Comment: Probably you need to check this on the appropriate forum as this one is focused on Salesforce.

Comment: I suspect that this part ``s.EventDate >= '8/5/2016'`` could be the culprit.

Comment: There are no Joins (Like that) in SOQL. If this is SQL then you are on the wrong forum

Comment: Even though it is happening in the marketing cloud?

Comment: Tagging is key. I added the `marketing-cloud` tag for you so the context is more clear.

Comment: You mentioned `_Sent` in your post but your query is referencing `_Click`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a curly quote in there: `‘MHAT_Email1'`

```
SELECT 
      s.SubscriberKey
    , ss.EmailAddress
    , MIN(s.EventDate) as 'FirstClickDate'
    , o.ACCT_NUM
    , o.ACCT_NM
    , o.BUYER_CONTACT_UID
    , o.CONTACT_GUID
    , o.FIRST_NM
    , o.LAST_NM
    , o.EMAIL_ADDR
    , o.PHONE
FROM _Click s 
JOIN _job j ON (j.JobID = s.JobID AND j.accountid = 1059291)
JOIN ENT._subscribers ss ON (s.SubscriberID = ss.SubscriberID)
JOIN [MHAT_ImportDE] o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.CONTACT_GUID
WHERE 
    j.EmailName = 'MHAT_Email1'
    and s.EventDate >= '8/5/2016'
Group by 
    s.SubscriberKey
    , ss.EmailAddress
    , o.ACCT_NUM
    , o.ACCT_NM
    , o.BUYER_CONTACT_UID
    , o.CONTACT_GUID
    , o.FIRST_NM
    , o.LAST_NM
    , o.EMAIL_ADDR
    , o.PHONE
```

A word of caution.  Joining to all of the system data views in a single query is a recipe for a timeout.  I'd recommend proactively giving each data view it's own query.